# SQL UPDATE where 2 fields are on the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables, `Order, Customer, OrderCustomer`:

**Order**:

```
order_number    customer_number
----------------------------------    
1               null
2               null
```

**Customer**:

```
customer_number    customer_code    
-----------------------------------
  33               z-99
  34               z-100
```

**OrderCustomer**:

```
order_number customer_code
----------------------------
  1            z-99
  2            z-100
```

I did try:

```
UPDATE order
SET o.[customer_number] = c.[customer_number]
FROM order AS o
INNER JOIN orderCustomer AS oc ON o.[order_number] = oc.[order_number]
INNER JOIN customer AS c ON oc.[customer_code] = c.customer_code
```

But running the query above throws an error:

> The multi-part identifier "o.customer_number" could not be bound.

How can I update `order.customer_number` with the values of `customer.customer_number` ?

Comment: `Order` is a T-SQL reserved keyword, and you should try to **avoid using it** as your table name. If you can't change it - then you must put the table name into square brackets in your `FROM` clause:  ` FROM [Order] AS o .....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the alias instead of the table. Also, don't include the alias in the SET clause. Last but not least you MUST wrap your table order in square brackets. You really should avoid using reserved words as object names.

```
UPDATE o
SET [customer_number] = c.[customer_number]
FROM [order] AS o
INNER JOIN orderCustomer AS oc
    ON o.[order_number] = oc.[order_number]
INNER JOIN customer AS c
    ON oc.[customer_code] = c.customer_code
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the alias for the `update`:

```
UPDATE o
    SET o.[customer_number] = c.[customer_number]
    FROM order o JOIN
         orderCustomer oc
         ON o.[order_number] = oc.[order_number] JOIN
         customer AS c
         ON oc.[customer_code] = c.customer_code;
```

SQL Server allows your syntax, magically recognizing that `order` refers to the `o` in the `FROM` clause.  The use of the table name when an alias has replaced it confuses me.

SQL Server thinks that what you are updating is called "orders", not "o", so the reference in the `SET` causes the problem.

Actual, SQL Server only allows you to update one table, so the alias is redundant in the `set`:

```
UPDATE o
    SET [customer_number] = c.[customer_number]
    FROM order o JOIN
         orderCustomer oc
         ON o.[order_number] = oc.[order_number] JOIN
         customer AS c
         ON oc.[customer_code] = c.customer_code;
```

This would work with `UPDATE order` as well, but I strongly encourage you to use the alias once you have defined it.